# overflow error---loop does not converge in function

Tags: excel, vba

'I want to call this function dpdxf in a main program with following constants, but it stops during first iteration giving a -ve value of dpdxf. Bust dpdxf always should be >0 or positive.

```
p1=40196684
p2=4019668
xf=320
PI=4*10^-11
t=20
n=0.4
k=20
wg=3*10^-6
H=46
w=0.006
qg=0.002
mug_p=0.04

'===================================================================

Function dpdxf(p1, p2, xf, PI, t, n, k, wg, H, w, qg, mug_p)

Static frpr

dpdxf = (p1 - p2 - 2 * qg / PI) / xf
FrGaF = 1
Static qgg

 Do
   frpr = dpdxf
        Do
         qgg = FrGaF

          FrGaF = -((H * wg * (-3 * 2 ^ (-1 / n) * k * n ^ (2 + 1 / n) * ((-2 * t + dpdxf * wf) / (k * n)) ^ (1 + 1 / n) - (2 * dpdxf ^ 2 * wg ^ 2) / (mug_p) - (2 *n * dpdxf ^ 2 * wg ^ 2) / (mug_p))) / (3 * (1 + n) * dpdxf))
        Loop While Abs(FrGaF - qgg) >= 0.00  

     dpdxf = (p1 - p2 - 2 * (FrGaF / PI)) / xf

 Loop Until Abs(dpdxf - frpr) <= 0.0001

End Function
```

Comment: I really wanna help you on this one, but the code is really hard to read with all those variable (i.e. frpr, dpdxf,k, n,t) sounds like banking or physics :). You may consider editing the code?

Comment: yes very true from banking, but cant reduce the code. But I can say that there are two unknowns FrGaF and dpdxf. Ijust declared qgg and frpr to apply loop condition. I feel my logic is not good enough because while calculating dpdxf its value does not converge but the iteration keeps going on and when it goes to a -ve value it gives an  overflow error.

Comment: will try and focus on it by tomorrow and if you allow it I might edit the code for others to follow more easily

Comment: sure thank you very much.. i hope u understand my problem in code.

Comment: I suggest format the posting with proper indentation and remove empty lines and _use the debugger_ to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Oh, and declare the arguments as `ByVal x as Double` otherwise they might be initialized as integer and division will not work properly.

Comment: So what is `PIndex` ? The code you posted is not well defined

Comment: For the values you have given, `dpdxf = (p1 - p2 - 2 * qg / PI) / xf` starts out being negative. Once it gets to this part of the equation: `((-2 * t + dpdxf * wf) / (k * n)) ^ (1 + 1 / n)` Excel chokes for obvious reasons.

Comment: How you got to know exactly this part , that you extracted from the equation, causing the problem? It will help me to check all equations in pieces...thank you very much for your input....

Comment: You can get the same result by hand: (40196684 - 4019668 - 2 * 0.002 / 4e-11) / 320 = -199447. Either your initial values are wrong, or your formula for guessing `dpdxf` is wrong.

Comment: Why can't you use the debugger to check the values. Press `F8` to step through the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Function dpdxf(ByVal p1 as Double, ByVal p2 as Double, ByVal xf as Double, ByVal PI as Double, _ 
               ByVal t as Double, ByVal n as Double, ByVal k as Double, ByVal wg as Double, _
               ByVal H as Double, ByVal w as Double, ByVal qg as Double, ByVal mug_p as Double)
```

So you do not end up dividing integer values. Also change your constants to `1#` or `2#` to declare them also as floating point numbers.

Comment: I want to solve FrGaF = ------  and dpdxf = (p1 - p2 - 2 * (FrGaF / PI)) / xf to get solution for dpdxf and FrGaF....